# %#@& : $!*^ :: SOFT : 5697 :: 8924 :?

Tags: cipher

If `%#@&` is coded as `$!*^` and `SOFT` is coded as `5697`.
What is the code for `8924`?

A) `#*%&`
B) `%#!*`
C) `#*%@`
D) `*#%@`

[image: actual puzzle]

Source: Puzzle comes from Indian book... For class 4 students olympiad exam - Unified Cyber Olympiad - class 4

I do not know the answer... Help me solve this.

Comment: Tried ASCII? From the second clue it seems unlikely but worth a shot (perhaps some rearrangement)

Comment: Yup tried ascii....no luck. if it helps here is the ascii for you..... 35 #   36 $   37 %   38 &   64 @  33 ! 42 *   94 ^     83 S   79 O   70 F   84 T   53 5   54 6   57 9   55 7   56 8   57 9   50 2   52 4

Comment: Since there isn't an obivious 1:1 correlation the question is unclear. Does the encoding of **SOFT** follow the first one, or is it done independently? So, is the problem coded serially after the first two, or independently?

Comment: Hey @Weather Vane I have updated the title as u suggested... In regards to your second query i have as much information as you do... It is the question and pic of the original question all I have nothing more nothing less :)

Comment: While this is in no way a valid answer, given the training that I was given for such Olympiads if the question seems to take to long use the answer with the most common characteristics (in this case option C) and move on since most of these tests are not generous with the time you get